# Ant + Coldspring

Tags: ant, coldfusion, coldspring

I am working with the new cfbuilder and using ANT to push my code to my dev server. One issue that keeps cropping up is when I make changes to my beans.xml file my ant build throws an exception on my beans.xml file.

This is the exception that I get:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\workingcopies\bpmMag\config\beans.xml:3: Unexpected element "{}beans" {antlib:org.apache.tools.ant}beans
```

Here is my build file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="build" default="" basedir=".">
<description>
    A description of what this build file does
</description>   

<!-- Location of working Copy -->
    <property name="workingCopy" value="C:\workingcopies\bpmMag" />

<!-- Location of testing server -->
    <property name="testServer" value="Z:\www\dev7.devstation\htdocs" />



<!-- Test Target -->
    <target name="test">
        <copy todir="${testServer}">
            <fileset dir="${workingCopy}">
                <exclude name="coldspring/**"/>
                <exclude name="**/*.project"/>
                <exclude name="settings.xml"/>
                <exclude name=".settings/**"/>
                <exclude name="build.xml"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>  
    </target>
```

Here is my beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans>

<!-- Advice Beans -->
<bean id="AdviceDAO" class="com.model.advice.dao.AdviceDAO">
    <constructor-arg name="dsn"><value>${dsn}</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="AdviceGateway" class="com.model.advice.gateway.AdviceGW">
    <constructor-arg name="dsn"><value>${dsn}</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="AdviceService" class="com.model.advice.service.AdviceSV">
    <constructor-arg name="adviceDAO">
        <ref bean="adviceDAO"/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name="adviceGateway">
        <ref bean="adviceGateway"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that your entire build file? Because it's missing the closing project tag

I copied your beans.xml and build.xml, added the end project tag, set up a simulation set of directories, and it worked as expected for me (i.e. no {} beans.... error)

Comment: For some reason I clipped the ending project tag off. 

After a bit more testing, I have been able to determine a few things.

If my beans.xml file is the only file to build it throws the exception.

If I have any other files that need to be built and my beans.xml file needs to be built as long as I am not running my build with the beans.xml file as my open document I do not get the error.